# Laravel/Lumen: How to return a single value from the first record matching WHERE clause

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm attempting to return a single column value from the first record matching my where WHERE clause. In the below example from my controller, I'm defining this result as $code. I can either get the first record or I can get a specific column value but not both.

First Record:
   $code = DB::table('codes')->where('redeemed', '0')->first();

Single Column Value:
   $code = DB::table('codes')->where('redeemed', '0')->value('code');

How can I do both in a single request?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `pluck`.

```
DB::table('codes')->where('redeemed', 0)->pluck('code');
```

Comment: But this doesn't limit the number of records returned. How do I incorporate ->first()?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! Thank you! DB::table('codes')->where('redeemed', 0)->pluck('code')->first()

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `select()` method:

```
DB::table('codes')->where('redeemed', '0')->select('code')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example:

```
$code = DB::table('codes')->where('redeemed', '0')->value('code');
```

This will already do what you want. The `value()` method calls `first()`, as can be seen in the definition of the method:

```
public function value($column)
{
    $result = (array) $this->first([$column]); // <-- call to first on query

    return count($result) > 0 ? reset($result) : null;
}
```